# How does High Purity Lead Solder react with Orthophosphoric acid

Tags: soldering

I am currently reviewing all processes and chemicals used in my firm and the one I came across this week is that we are using a high purity lead solder with Orthophosphoric acid. Ignoring the CLAW regs on the lead solder, as I am now all over this issue, can anyone explain why Orthophosphoric acid would give a better join/result than not using it?

Comment: I'm not sure where this belongs, but it isn't here. Even assuming that you are talking about joining electronic components (which seems unlikely), discussion of the *chemical* properties of the materials involved is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acid is acting as a flux and not using it is likely to result in poor solder joints. It isn't a suitable flux for electronic components.